# filebeat add_fields processor with condition

Tags: filebeat

I'd like to add a field "app" with the value "apache-access" to every line that is exported to Graylog by the Filebeat "apache" module.

The following configuration should add the field as I see a "event_dataset"="apache.access" field in Graylog but to does not do anything.
If I remove the condition, the "add_fields" processor does add a field though.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: false
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
setup.kibana:
output.logstash:
  hosts: [ "localhost:5044" ]

processors:
- add_fields:
    when:
      equals:
        event_dataset: "apache.access"
    target: ""
    fields:
      app: "apache-access"

logging.level: info
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason the field is called "event.dataset" in filebeat but displayed as "event_dataset" in Graylog.